# iOS Settings app integration

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I've got an Alloy app and I'm trying to put some configuration into the Settings app in iOS.

I've added the Root.plist file here:
/app/platform/iphone/Settings.Bundle

The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>StringsTable</key>
<string>Root</string>
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Service</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>username</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Email address</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But nothing appears in the settings app for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an iOS bug in the simulator where if your app was running, even in background, when a new version was installed, the settings were not updated until you completed closed the app and relaunched it.  Closing the simulator with the app running did NOT resolve the issue.  TBH, I have not tested this lately, I am just in the habit of closing my app before I rebuild.  Try completely closing your app, then relaunching it and see if the settings update.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that on device and simulator but it's still not working. Strange.